# If..Else Statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to write a If..Else statement that will write if at least two children's tickets
    are purchased, the program adds the message

```
"We hope your kids enjoy the show!"
```

at the end of the existing output.

```
    $adultTickets = $_POST['adultTickets'];
    $childTickets = $_POST['childTickets'];

    $totalCost = $adultTickets * 6.50 + $childTickets * 4.50;
    if ($childTickets >= 2);
    print("<p>We hope your kids enjoy the show!</p>");

    else 
    print("<p>You ordered $adultTickets adult tickets and
    $childTickets children's tickets.</p>");
    print("<p>Your cost is $$totalCost.</p>");
```

Comment: if(condition){
//do something
}
else{
//do something else
}

Comment: That didnt help at all.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Andy has posted your error message in one's answer, that should have been done by you. It's also unclear if you intend to always display "You ordered..." part and only add "We hope..." after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($childTickets >= 2);
                       ^  Remove this
```

With that there, it fails with a

```
Line : 10,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE
```

If you remove it and have 2 adult and 1 child tickets the output is:

```
You ordered 2 adult tickets and 1 children's tickets.

Your cost is $17.5.
```

If you have 2 adult, 2 children the output is:

```
We hope your kids enjoy the show!

Your cost is $22.
```

Edit:

In response to your comment, you want code like this.

```
print("<p>You ordered $adultTickets adult tickets and
$childTickets children's tickets.</p>");

if ($childTickets >= 2)
    print("<p>We hope your kids enjoy the show!</p>");
```

You don't need the `else` condition if you are always printing the "You ordered..." line.

Comment: I still need it to say this:You ordered $adultTickets adult tickets and $childTickets children's tickets. Your cost is $$totalCost.

Comment: Then you don't need an if/else. You just need the `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($childtickets >=2)
{
   echo 'We hope your Kids enjoy the show';
}
else
{
   echo 'sorry';
}
```